# WPF Change Visibility of ComboBoxItem on a databound ComboBox

Tags: wpf, vb.net, linq, combobox

I have a combo box that is databound via a linq query.  One of the fields is called CSVError and is either a 1 or 0.

I have a separate combobox that has the options PDF and CSV.

When PDF is selected, the first combobox should appear normally.  When CSV is selected, the first combobox should have comboboxItems with a background set to red when CSVError = 1 and normal when CSVError = 0.

I have tried this...

```
 <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem" x:Key="CSVError">
     <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding bolCSVError}" Value="0">
           <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding bolCSVError}" Value="1">
           <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </DataTrigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
```

and then in code, when the PDF/CSV combobox is changed...

```
If sender.selectedValue.strExtension = "CSV" Then
   ReportList.ItemContainerStyle = Resources.Item("CSVError")
Else
   ReportList.ItemContainerStyle = Nothing
End If
```

This doesn't seem to work.  Using Visual Studio debugger, I can see that the VB.Net code is being executed properly, but the styles aren't being applied properly (red backgrounds aren't applied at all).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind...turns out bolCSVError didn't exist in the bound data...added it to my linq query and it worked fine.